# how to do crochet patterned curtains (grandmother like)

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

I need your help, i have no explanation how to do these curtains
- can someone explain, what is the smartest way to model these?
- how can i use it in the best way for a cloth sim?

[image]

Best regards,
Marc

Answer (score 3):

Its not necessary to do the curtain with real geometry, just use a normal cloth simulation and create the visual effect with the material using a texture as mask for an transparent-shader

[image]
[image]

Comment: If this would be to flat for you up close, you could use a normal map additionally